# What does a function with multiple return statements return?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

This is from an exercise out of Head First JavaScript Programming book.

```
    function findCarInLot(car) {
            for (var i = 0; i < lot.length; i++) {
                if (car === lot[i]) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

    var lot = [chevy, taxi, fiat1, fiat2];
```

I'm not going to write all the code basically the chevy, taxi, etc, are objects and the function is assigned one of the four objects and that value is give to a variable in this exercise. My question is what is going on with:

```
    return -1;
```

So doesn't that get returned when the function completes? Or is it negated when

```
    return i;
```

happens? Or are both values returned? Could someone sort this out for my poor brain and tell me what the rules are here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on which return it hits, that will be the only thing it returns

```
function findCarInLot(car) {
            for (var i = 0; i < lot.length; i++) {
                if (car === lot[i]) {
                    return i; // If this if statement is true I will return here and this function will end and I will never make it to the next return
                }
            }
            return -1; // This will only get called if the above if statement is false
        }

    var lot = [chevy, taxi, fiat1, fiat2];
```

To me this function looks like, if you called it, it will loop through the car array, and if it finds said car in the array, it will return the index for that car.

If no car is found in the array, it will return `-1` meaning the car doesn't have an index thus it is not in the array.

So, if we have

```
var lot = [chevy, taxi, fiat1, fiat2];
```

and we run

```
console.log(findCarInLot("fiat1")); // This will return 2 (Third element of the array)
```

This is returned from the `return i` inside the if statement and you will never see `return -1`

But if we do

```
console.log(findCarInLot("lamadamadingdong")); // This will return -1 as it was never found in the array of cars
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps a lot. Just getting to the point where I'm learning about how consistently inconsistent JavaScript consistently is. Good to know there is a solid rule here lol.